# I am trying to render a figure on a web browser using python flask from two user entered data fields

Tags: javascript, python, flask, plotly-python

I have a function that plots a Plotly figure that needs 2 inputs to work. A user would enter data into two fields that would feed this function. I am able to make it work with 1 field but would like to learn how to gather input from multiple fields. Here is my app.py and the HTML file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/callback', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def cb():
    data1 = request.args.get('data1')
    data2 = request.args.get('data2')
    
    return gm(data1,data2)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('chartsajax.html', graphJSON=gm())

def gm(country_name_1='',country_name_2=''):

    country = str(country_name_1)+' '+str(country_name_2)
    print('country: '+country)
    df = pd.DataFrame(px.data.gapminder())
    fig = px.line(df[df['country'] == country], x="year", y="gdpPercap")
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    return graphJSON

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=False)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function cb(selection1,selection2) {
            $.getJSON({
                url: "/callback", data: { 'data1': selection1,'data2': selection2 }, success: function (result) {
                    Plotly.react('chart', result, {});;
                }
            });

            
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="font-family:arial, sans-serif">
    <h1>GDP per Capita Over Time</h1>
    <h2>Choose your country as "United Kingdom" by entering "United" in one text field then "Kingdom" into the next</h2>

    <p>Make sure you spell "United" with a capital letter, e.g. "United" </p>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onchange="cb(this.value)">

    <p>Make sure you spell "Kingdom" with a capital letter, e.g. "Kingdom" </p>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onchange="cb(this.value)">

    <div id="chart" class="chart"></div>
    <div id="png_chart"></div>
</body>

<script>
    cb("");
</script>
</html>
```

It is only pulling the value of the first text field because I don't know how to pull from the second one too. So, when United and Kingdom are entered, the function input is "United None". Also, it is acting like I'm pressing enter when I go enter text in the second field. Maybe a submit button would be better?

Thanks in advance!